# How to fix 'CameraPreview' is missing in type in Ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I wanna build a Ionic camera preview app, and I installed @capacitor-community/camera-preview. I have declared the CameraPreview as Plugin in the HomePage.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PluginRegistry, Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
const {CameraPreview} = Plugins;
import {CameraPreviewOptions, CameraPreviewPictureOptions} from '@capacitor-community/camera-preview';
import '@capacitor-community/camera-preview';
```

***Each time I run the ionic serve to deploy the app, I get this error:***

```
Error: node_modules/@capacitor-community/camera-preview/node_modules/@capacitor/core/types/definitions-internal.d.ts:16:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'CapacitorInstance' incorrectly extends interface 'CapacitorGlobal'.
  Types of property 'Plugins' are incompatible.
    Property 'CameraPreview' is missing in type '{ [pluginName: string]: { [prop: string]: any; }; }' but required in type 'PluginRegistry'.

16 export interface CapacitorInstance extends CapacitorGlobal {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@capacitor-community/camera-preview/dist/esm/definitions.d.ts:3:9
    3         CameraPreview: CameraPreviewPlugin;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'CameraPreview' is declared here.
```

I tried installing capacitor 3 but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Ref : https://github.com/capacitor-community/apple-sign-in/issues/22

patrickbussmann commented on 1 Jun
You must only install it without the tag.

npm install capacitor-community/camera-preview

Then you have the master branch installed and you can use with Capacitor 3.

it happened to me

Comment: Please phrase and format your answer clearly instead of copying some text.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30073639)

Comment: This solution actually worked for me. What @Aydin was trying to stipulate was that instead of using @capacitor-community/camera-preview you just install without the `@` and it then uses the master branch, rectifying outdated type declarations. Kudos @Aydin :)